# PNP- NPN light flasher

Tags: transistors, bjt, npn, basic, pnp

I understand that

1. R1 and R2 make a voltage divider.
2. initially Q1 is not conductive, so is Q2?
3. initially C1 acts as short circuit, so flashes the light L1 for a moment?

Please correct me if wrong.
Can someone breakdown this circuit step by step? Is there an easy analogy to solve such combinational transistor circuits generally?

credits: referred from the book "Getting started in Electronics" by Forrest M Mims
[image]

Comment: 2) Initially not conductive. 3) No, not initially.

Comment: ok. So the initial voltage is not high enough to light up L1? would you please mind breaking down the working of the circuit step by step?

Comment: It is a very good start. But, it takes a little more than that .To get insight & understanding of how the circuitry works, try [Circuit Simulators](https://www.electronics-lab.com/top-ten-online-circuit-simulators/).

Comment: If you didn't create the schematic, you need to credit the creator, usually by posting a link. Site rules.

Comment: Look here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/338128/is-this-an-astable-multivibrator/338163#338163 or here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/261288/understand-2-transistors-npn-pnp-flasher-circuit-working/261407#261407

Comment: @G36 thanks for the link. This one almost looks same. Except, I notice the polarized capacitor is connected in reverse. But does it still work the same nevertheless? Also the pull-up resistor for the Q2 base is missing in your example.

Comment: @jay thanks. I will try it out.

Comment: Yes, the working principal of a circuit will not change https://tinyurl.com/yjdkoqyb